GNOME .Desktop Entry for Wine Executable Not Working
I have a custom wine prefix installed and I want to run a specific .exe file but the .Desktop entry won't work.
In the terminal this command opens the software without any issue at all
env WINEPREFIX=/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows wine /home/$USERNAME/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows/drive_c/Program\ Files/Adobe/Adobe\ Photoshop\ 2021/photoshop.exe

But when I create a Desktop entry it shows

Desktop file didn't Specify Exec field

My photoshop.desktop file:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Photoshop
Exec=env WINEPREFIX=/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows wine /home/$USERNAME/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows/drive_c/Program\ Files/Adobe/Adobe\ Photoshop\ 2021/photoshop.exe
Categories=graphics;
Actions=app_settings;

Then I tried changing the dir with " or ' or \ or //// and //, nothing seems to work. Maybe I am doing something wrong with the correct dir format. Like
Exec=env WINEPREFIX=/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows wine '/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows/drive_c/Program\ Files/Adobe/Adobe\ Photoshop\ 2021/photoshop.exe'

or
Exec=env WINEPREFIX=/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows wine '/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop 2021/photoshop.exe'

or
Exec=env WINEPREFIX=/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows wine /home////$USERNAME////.local////share////wineprefixes////Windows////drive_c////Program Files// Adobe////Adobe// Photoshop// 2021////photoshop.exe' 



Since I am unable to find an immediate solution, one workaround I have is to use the working command as a separate bash script and invoke it from the shortcut itself through its Exec field
Now my working .desktop file looks like this
[[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Photoshop
Exec=/home/{$USERNAME}/.wine/custom_run_scripts/run_photoshop.sh
Categories=Graphics;
Actions=app_settings;

And the run_photoshop.sh contains the working run command like below,
env WINEPREFIX=/home/{$USERNAME}/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows wine /home/{$USERNAME}/.local/share/wineprefixes/Windows/drive_c/Program\ Files/Adobe/Adobe\ Photoshop\ 2021/photoshop.exe

Use your actual username at the place of {$USERNAME}

This is what I do. I have a whole directory called .wine-dregs full of 'em! Oh, bitter dregs.
